# Showing source code in devtools using Vite

Tags: reactjs, vite

How do I stop **Vite** from hiding the source code of my website ( specifically **react components** )
After building the project the only thing I can see is a compressed javascript file containing everything, unlike create react app which shows all the components by default, which setting do I have to change ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I found out how to do it, hope this helps someone.
just add this to the config file :

```
export default defineConfig({
plugins: [react()],
build: { //add this property
    sourcemap: true,
},
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I added the property, restarted everything, and I still don't get any sources of my application in the Sources pane of devtools.